# What are the correct cost mathematics for "Animate Object"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

I have a character (alchemist with Promethean Disciple) who has the Craft Construct feat.
I would like to make some Animated Objects.
The [page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs) on the SRD gives me a formula for the cost on the animation, namely ((HD+CP)*1000)/2.

By this math, using [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object) for information on HD and CP for each size, I have the following costs for Animating objects via Craft Construct.
Tiny: 1000,
Small: 1500,
Medium: 2500,
Large: 3500,
Huge: 5500,
Gargantuan: 7500,
Colossal: 8500.

However. The first linked page also has a *table* , that helpfully lists costs for various constructs, including Animated Objects:
Tiny: 125,
Small: 1000,
Medium: 2250,
Large: 6250,
Huge: 12500,
Gargantuan: 20000,
Colossal: 30000.

What are the correct costs for using Animate Object via the Craft Construct rules?

Answer (score 3):

What you seem not to have noticed is that the (HD + CP) × 500 formula is listed under the heading 'Alternate Creation Rules', but that the price table is not under that heading.  The non-alternate rules for crafting animated objects are given under the 'Animated Objects' heading, and indicate that the price of crafting an animated object is based on the creature's CR.  Both the rules and the table come from *Ultimate Magic*, pp. 111-112, where the fact that the price mentioned is meant to be taken from the table is more obvious than the SRD page makes it.

Comment: But the 'Alternative Creation Rules' ARE the rules for creating Animated Objects with Craft Construct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, the rules for creating Animated Object with Craft Construct are under the 'Animated Objects' head.